# Single vs multiple fragment containers

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am using a bottom navigation bar in my project with MVC architecture. I am used to creating projects where I use only one fragment container (usually I use MainActivity.kt/main_activity.xml), switching my fragments in and out depending on user interaction.

Now since I am using a bottom navigation bar that is a part of main_activity.xml (which I use as my fragment container) which I think should be used for all those fragments that contain bottom navigation bar, and not for all the other fragments that are not a part of the bottom navigation bar.

Should I create a second activity/xml, as a 2nd fragment container, for all my fragments that don't contain bottom navigation bar (for instance, pressing a button that opens a new fragment that has nothing to do and doesn't contain a bottom navigation bar)? Or should I try to cram all that into a single container? What would be the best approach for this particular situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my humble opinion, I think you don't have to create another activity for your non-bottom Navigation Fragments.
It gonna be OK if you used the same MainActivity for that.
My other recommendation is to use **Navigation Component**, make one **NavHostFragment** act as your fragments(destinations) container.

Explore [this article](https://medium.com/@freedom.chuks7/how-to-use-jet-pack-components-bottomnavigationview-with-navigation-ui-19fb120e3fb9) to implement Navigation Component with bottom navigation.

Also, [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/navigation-architecture-component-for-the-rest-of-us-faafa890e5) will let you know how to transfer between fragments.